# 25A SIP Solid State Relay Question

Tags: solid-state-relay

I have been testing with the [SSRF-240D25R](http://elcodis.com/parts/861240/SSRF-240D25.html#datasheet) to see his application on shutting down a load current that in my case is mains powered from the grid.

In order to see if the relay stops the currents flow as soon as I stop feeding the control side, I did a test where I put a LED on the load side and turned on the control side. I expect to see the LED turn on when I feed the control and turn off as soon as I turned off the control side. In the end, only one part of the experiment went as expected the LED turned on but stayed on long after a shut down the control side. I can´t see what might be the problem even though it should be something simple to resolve.

Here is an electric scheme of the montage:

[image]

In summary, the SSRelays+Detect is the 12 V that I use to feed my control side, to activate the Mosfet Q1 I apply 3.3 V (SSRelaysDrive), voltage converted from the 12 V to bias a voltage regulator and in this experiment I used my STM32 Nucleo, "MCUB", as the load.

Comment: You cannot test an SCR or Triac based SSR with a DC load. When you turn the LED on, enough current will flow to exceed the holding current of the SCR (and only one of them is on).

Answer (score 0):

Your datasheet tells us that this is a "25A SIP Solid State Relay With Paired SCR Output, Integral Heatsink". This sounds as though it is a pair of back to back thyristors and will behave rather like a triac. Thyristors and triacs work well on AC circuits but are not much use in DC circuits unless the DC is rectified mains with no smoothing.

[image]

*Figure 1. Triacs (or thyristors in this case) once switched on remain on until the current through them falls below the hold-on value. With a steady DC supply this never happens. [Image source](https://lednique.com/bulbs/dimmers-for-leds/).*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb6rKT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. AC test circuit.*

Try repeating your test will a small transformer - say 12 V or so - and a couple of back-to-back LEDs with current limiting resistor.